# SwiftUI: present view growing out of tapped view and dismiss shrinking back to view?

Tags: swiftui

I need to present a view G (green) when I tap on a view O (orange). I need G to grow out of O when G is presented, animating its frame from O's frame and fading in at the same time.

When I dismiss G, I need it to fade out and animate back to O's frame.

Here's the code I have put together to try to achieve this.

```
struct TestView: View {


    @State private var expand = false
    @Namespace private var presentDismissTransition

    var body: some View {
        
        
        
        ZStack {
            
            VStack {
                
                Spacer()
                
                // Circle
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50.0)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "test", in: presentDismissTransition)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemOrange))
                    .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)))
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        expand.toggle()
                    }
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            
            if expand {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50.0)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "test", in: presentDismissTransition)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGreen))
                    .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        expand.toggle()
                    }
            }
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
        
        
        
    }

}
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

Unfortunately it's not quite there. What's not working:

- The O view is animating. I do not want it to animate. **I simply need G
  to grow out of O**.
- On dismiss, G immediately switches to O and O goes back to its
  original frame. **On dismiss I need G to shrink back and fade out
  into O**

How can I update this code to achieve what shown/described?

Important:
I am working on this just as an example. Ultimate goal for me is to be able to apply this present / dismiss transition on multiple views on screen. Will eventually apply this effect on a grid scenario where I tap on a cell, and the details open growing out of the cell and then on details dismiss the details view (G) shrinks back and fade into the tapped cell....

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65168030/12299030?

Comment: trying to figure out how to apply that answer to my case. Not sure yet.